# Can not login in messagebird with my account

Tags: authentication, sms-gateway, messagebird

A few days ago I wanted to try the [messagebird](https://messagebird.com/en/) service to send SMS.

I created an account, they gave me a credit of 10 units and I did tests to send sms, everything went well.

But when I recharged my account with `15$`, after a few minutes my account is no longer accessible, when I try to log in [dashboard.messagebird.com/en/login](https://dashboard.messagebird.com/en/login) I am automatically redirected to the [dashboard.messagebird.com/en/sign-up](https://dashboard.messagebird.com/en/sign-up) page. it's as if the account was never created when I sent the money.

More than 24 hours ago I tried to create a new account and put the money the thing same happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like a problem you better contact [MessageBird support](https://support.messagebird.com/hc/en-us).
You can email them at support@messagebird.com too.

Comment: Thanks @marcel.corso, I did this 2 days ago but so far no response from them.
Thats why i came here, maybe someone here has had this problem using messagebird.

Comment: Right they finally response(By Fraud Prevention Specialist) saying that  my  account was `blocked due to signs of fraudulent activity` but it was just a misunderstanding.  I have just to response provide same information about my company and i hope every thing will be fine.

Comment: Cool, they solved my problem. my account is now active thank you.